# array out of bounds or wrong equals to nullptr? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling

I have a method that's causing me trouble. I get segmentation fault error. I ran my test through gdb and got that the problem lies in the following method
shoppingList array contains pointers to Product class objects.
What I'm trying to do here is add an item, I iterate through the array until I find a nullptr or empty space. The size of the array is 20, and it was initially all set to nullptr with the constructor. 
number =20
how the array was in CustomerOrder.h

```
public:
static const size_t number = 20;
private:
std::array<Product*, number> shoppingList;
```

how I initialized it in the constructor:

```
CustomerOrder::CustomerOrder()
: shoppingList()
{

}
```

And this is the problem method.

```
void CustomerOrder::addItem(Product *p)
{
bool space = false;
int counter=0;
while(space==false || counter < 20 )
{
if(shoppingList[counter] == nullptr )
{
shoppingList[counter] = p;
space == true;
}
counter++;
}
```

Comment: `space == true` doesn't assign true to space. It only compares it. You probably meant `space = true`?

Comment: I think most compilers would give a warning about `space == true;`.  Got warnings enabled?

Comment: In addition to the answers and what Rosme said, you can make the loop a lot simpler (in my eyes) by changing the condition to `while(counter < 20)` and instead of `space = true;` you put `break`. That way you don't need the `space` variable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `&&` in the while clause

because `space == false` it will be (`true || false`) you'll always have a true statement if you do an && statement you're looking to make sure both cases are still true vs. one or the other true.

```
while(space==false && counter < 20 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time this loop runs:

```
while(space==false || counter < 20 )
{
    // ...
}
```

it will fill the array with the pointer `p`. The the next time you run through the loop, it'll write `p` past the end of the array. I think you want an `&&` instead of a `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your condition:

```
while(space==false || counter < 20 )
```

This should be changed to:

```
while(space==false && counter < 20 )
```

A better way would be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < CustomerOrder::number; ++i) {
    if (shoppingList [counter] == nullptr) {
        shoppingList [counter] = p ;
        break ;
    }
}
```

If you have `#include <algorithm>`, then this could be further simplified to :

```
auto iter = std::find (std::begin (shoppingList), std::end (shoppingList), nullptr) ;
if (iter != std::end (shoppingList) {
    *iter = p ;
}
```